# Rails Postgresql Query Speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

All,

I have inherited a database that was already created and I am making changes to it.  I am fairly new to Rails and Postgresql but familiar with DB programming.  I am looking for some query speed advice.

I'll use the following example

I have a table called "persons" and in that table, there is a "boolean" called "isEmployee".  I need to expand this from a boolean to something that has another layer of depth.  I see the following options

string - make tags like "employee", "manager, etc. and then my "isEmployee" equation is "if it is employee or manager"

integer - make enumerated values where say "employee=1". "manager=2" and my isEmployee equation is "if it is 1 or 2".

I am trying to understand the following
   - How badly will my query speed be impacted if I go from a boolean to one of these in order to provide expand-ability to my model?
   - If i do this, which should I use, string or integer?

Thanks

Comment: I'd definitely advise using integers instead of strings for effectiveness. It'd be much easier to keep up with using numbers that you'd later relate to their "word" equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Oscar.  That is what I was leaning towards.  I feel like an integer compare would be much faster than a string compare.

Comment: For performance, don't rely on "feel". Measure. If you're not going to measure, then don't worry about performance, focus on what's readable and maintainable.

Comment: You've left out an option: enums. Don't know how well Rails supports them, but PostgreSQL's enum types are designed for exactly this use.

Comment: Good advice Craig.  I standardized the type "employee" across the database and made it so my controller base class handles pulling the employee off the params and storing it in the variable "@employee".  I then make all my controllers just blindly use the clause ".where(employee: @employee)".  The good news is that the code is now 100% readable and clean.

I currently have the employee represented by a string.  It appears as though the performance was degraded ~20%.  the good news is that my code is now super clean and I can easily convert it to a integer (or possibly enum)